# Bazaar: I deleted the trunk directory. Can I make another or delete the project so I can start over?

Tags: version-control, wamp, bazaar, wampserver

I've been trying to set up Bazaar for a project I'm doing in WAMP. I followed the tutorial [here](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/explorer/en/guide/processes/starting_a_project.html) and initialized it as C:/Bazaar/MyProject, and this made a trunk directory. I can't remember exactly what I did, but I switched around a bunch of files on my computer because I couldn't figure out how to set up the project so that I could still run my files on WampServer. Anyway, for some stupid reason I went into the file system and deleted the trunk directory.

Now I can't add any files to my project, and I can't seem to add the trunk back. I can't reinitialize the project because it gives me an error: `bzr: ERROR: File exists: u'C:/Bazaar/MyProject/.bzr': [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: u'C:/Bazaar/MyProject/.bzr'`. How can I re-add the trunk or delete the project? Just making another folder called "trunk" through Windows Explorer didn't work and my Google-fu is failing me.

Bonus question: how should I set up a Bazaar project so I can still test my files on WampServer? Currently no PHP will run unless the file is kept in `C:/wamp/www` or a subdirectory of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do right now is to delete the .bzr folder and reinitialize the whole thing again.

For your second question, just export the source files to the C:/wamp/www folder.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out that the .bzr file was hidden and that's why I couldn't delete it before. Now it seems fine :)

Second part: maybe I'm not understanding version control, but wouldn't this be kind of impractical? Would I have to export a new version every time I want to see a change in a browser?

Comment: @user460847 Not really.  You could make C:/wamp/www your working directory instead.  I do this when I'm the only one who touch the source files.